# my simple animate function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

my html is:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="widthPlus">increase </button>
        <div id="bod"> hai </div>
        <img id="tree" src="http://www.rangde.org/newsletter/nov11/images/real_tree.png" width="350"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

my script is:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#widthPlus").click(function(){ 
        var currentwidth = $('#tree').attr('width'); 
        var currentwidthNum = parseFloat(currentwidth, 350); 
        var newwidth = currentwidthNum+5; 
        $('#tree').animate({'width', newwidth}, 5000); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

i am trying to increase(5px) the image width when click a button [my jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/XjaD5/2/)

Comment: How did you come up with a 2nd parameter for `parseFloat()`?  Also, you need to use jQuery's `.width()` to reliably get the actual width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#widthPlus").click(function() {

        $('#tree').animate({
            'width': '+=5'
        }, 5000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jE9HM/).

Comment: i check on my FF browser it doesnt animate

Comment: @bondythegreat: I checked on mine and it does.

Answer (score 1):

You have many syntax errors, and also are not using some of the functions properly.  I would highly recommend using the documentation for things like parseFloat and jQuery animate.  Using Chrome's inspect tool or Firefox's firebug, you will be able to see the obvious javascript errors that are happening and be able to debug.

Here's a modified version of your code that works (so you can learn): http://jsfiddle.net/XjaD5/5/

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#widthPlus").click(function(){
        var currentwidth = $('#tree').width();

        var newwidth = currentwidth+5;
         $('#tree').animate({'width': newwidth}, 5000);
        return false;
  });
   });
```

Alex's version is a much better and elegant solution, however.